# Can I install oracle 11g on both windows and ubuntu running on dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, java, oracle

I have windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04 installed in dual boot on my laptop. I have oracle 11g enterprise edition installed on windows. I want to install oracle 11g express edition on ubuntu. Previously, I tried to do so and followed [this link](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2014/03/18/installing-java-oracle-11g-r2-express-edition-and-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-64-bit/). I ended up a non-functioning oracle on ubuntu and a crashed one on windows, which worked fine earlier. Was it caused due to any fault in my installation process or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it again and ended up with a working oracle11gXE on Ubuntu. But my oracle11gEnterprise on windows showed that it is missing some Listener. Apparently the listener automatically stops when system boots.
I am certain about using correctly each and every step. The only thing I'm fuzzy about is that the same defaults 8080@1521.
I had to choose my way therefore and now, this answer is written on Ubuntu 14.04 :D